# Simple JQuery code- Logic is correct but alert doesn't popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Need help to fix simple JQuery function. Below code expected to show an alert, but no output at anytime. I'm new to this stuff. So correct me if something went wrong.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>

<script>

$('#check').click(function() {

if ( $('#city').val() == '' )
{
    alert('Empty!!!');
}
else
{
    alert('Contains: ' + $('#city').val() );
}

});

</script> 
</head>
<body>
<h3>Registration form</h3>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="">
City: <input type="text" name="city" id="city"><br>
Last name: <input type="text" name="LastName" value="Mouse"><br>
Phone number: <input type="text" name="Last" value="Mouse"><br>

<button id="check">Check</button>
</form>
```

Comment: You need to wrap your code in a document ready handler - `$(document).ready(function() {...` or `$(function(){...`

Comment: Jay's right, explanation: script is before HTML output, thus at runtime the #check element doesn't exist, yet.

Comment: It's unfair mark to as duplicate, given reference is different from what I have asked. It would be helpful if @Frederic can revert  since I'm new to this stuff.

Comment: @Sivakumar, do you mean the duplicate does not answer your question?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi duplicate might be the answer. But when I search or before I know the exact answer or before I post a stackoverflow question as a new person can't figure out the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use **[document.ready](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)**  a function to execute when the DOM is fully loaded.

wrap the code inside document ready function

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
   // write you code
    //  $('#check').click(function () {

});
```